# require_once strips or removes URL parameters

Tags: php, get, global-variables, url-parameters, require-once

I'm passing a URL with parameters to an *index.php* page that contains 2 `require_once` functions calling template and config files that output the final page.

To elaborate:

URL with parameters `/index.php?param=cat`
is passed to *index.php* which contains:

```
<?php

require_once('funnel_config.php');
require_once('template.php');
?>
```

this then loads the 2 files and in this process the URL parameter is stripped out.

Here's a screencast showing what I mean: http://screencast.com/t/gzEQFGQknV8M.

How can I ensure the url parameter persists when using require_once?

Is there an alternative method to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: not using the `require_once` functions ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the URL parameter being "stripped out"? `$_GET` etc. persist in included files.

Comment: Mm ... you must be doing something else wrong there. POST and GET params persist in required or included files. Mean you can easily access them inside those.

Comment: The url begins as `https://test.com?url=cat` and by the time it has loaded, it appears as `https://test.com`. Somewhere in the process the parameters are lost.

Comment: Here's a screencast showing what I mean: http://screencast.com/t/gzEQFGQknV8M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

URL parameters are NOT affected by loading files via `require_once` or `include`. Further investigation into the inner workings of this system identified a function within a php library called goToCleanURL(). Commented this function out and now URL parameters behave as expected.

Thanks to the community for the advice that prompted me to dig a little deeper into the code.